Flutter: TabBar's tabs are overlapping widgets that are present before it
As the title said, tabbar is over lapping widgets present before it when the screensize is small
I have wrapped stats in my app in Wrap so that they stil can be visible in smaller screen sizes
Now i have some multiple charts to be shown so i put each chart in a tab view and tab bar that has tabs in it to view the charts. When the screen size is small the tab bar is coming up(from screenshot#1 to screenshot#2) or overlapping the widgets present before it.
And also if there are better ways to do things than my current approach please educate me.
Screenshot#1:

Screenshot#2:

Defintion of tabs:
List<Widget> tabs = [
                        const Tab(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.local_gas_station_outlined),
                          text: "Mileage",
                          iconMargin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                        ),
                        const Tab(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.pin_drop_outlined),
                          text: "Distance",
                          iconMargin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                        ),
                        const Tab(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.timer_outlined),
                          text: "Duration",
                          iconMargin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                        ),
                      ];

return Scaffold(
body: DefaultTabController(
                          initialIndex: defaultGraphTabIndex,
                          length: views.length,
                          child: SafeArea(
                            child: Scrollbar(
                              controller: _scrollController,
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                controller: _scrollController,
                                child: Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 18, left: 18, right: 18),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      // Stats Column:
                                      Column(
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: (MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .height >=
                                                    MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .width)
                                                ? MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .height *
                                                    1 /
                                                    6
                                                : MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                        .size
                                                        .width *
                                                    1 /
                                                    6,
                                            child: Wrap(
                                              spacing: 16,
                                              children: [
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: double.maxFinite,
                                                  child: Wrap(
                                                      spacing: 8,
                                                      alignment: WrapAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                            "Total money spent during",
                                                            style:
                                                                semiBold18()),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width:
                                                              double.maxFinite,
                                                          child: Wrap(
                                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                WrapCrossAlignment
                                                                    .center,
                                                            alignment:
                                                                WrapAlignment
                                                                    .spaceBetween,
                                                            children: [
                                                              DropdownButton(
                                                                  value: dropDownItems[
                                                                      dropDownMenuItemIndex],
                                                                  items: dropDownItems
                                                                      .map(
                                                                          (value) {
                                                                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                                      value:
                                                                          value,
                                                                      child: Text(
                                                                          value),
                                                                    );
                                                                  }).toList(),
                                                                  onChanged:
                                                                      (_) {
                                                                    setState(
                                                                        () {
                                                                      dropDownMenuItemIndex =
                                                                          dropDownItems
                                                                              .indexOf(_!);
                                                                    });
                                                                  }),
                                                              Row(
                                                                mainAxisSize:
                                                                    MainAxisSize
                                                                        .min,
                                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                    CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                        .center,
                                                                children: [
                                                                  Text(NumberFormat(
                                                                          "#,###.##")
                                                                      .format(
                                                                          moneySpent)),
                                                                  IconButton(
                                                                      onPressed:(){...}
                                                                      icon: const Icon(
                                                                          Icons
                                                                              .edit))
                                                                ],
                                                              )
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ]),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                5 /
                                                12,
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            TabBar(
                                              tabs: tabs,
                                              isScrollable: true,
                                              tabAlignment: TabAlignment.center,
                                            ),
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: ConstrainedBox(
                                                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                                    minHeight:
                                                        MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                                .size
                                                                .height /
                                                            4),
                                                child: TabBarView(
                                                  children: views,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                      ),)```


try removing the height

@Md.YeasinSheikh which height?

Top  of  TabBar and  Wrap

I removed height of the parent column and it is fixed tysm!

the flexible widget is wrapped around the tabbar to allow it to take up only the necessary space.
the Expanded widget is wrapped around the Tabbar view to ensure that it takes up the remaining space below the tabbar.
here's the example....
return Scaffold(
    body: DefaultTabController(
                              initialIndex: defaultGraphTabIndex,
                              length: views.length,
                              child: SafeArea(
                                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                    controller: _scrollController,
                                    child: Container(
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 18, left: 18, right: 18),
                                      child: Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                        children: [
                                          // Stats Column:
                                          Column(
                                            children: [
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: (MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .height >=
                                                        MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .width)
                                                    ? MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .height *
                                                        1 /
                                                        6
                                                    : MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                            .size
                                                            .width *
                                                        1 /
                                                        6,
                                                child: Wrap(
                                                  spacing: 16,
                                                  children: [
                                                    SizedBox(
                                                      width: double.maxFinite,
                                                      child: Wrap(
                                                          spacing: 8,
                                                          alignment: WrapAlignment
                                                              .spaceBetween,
                                                          children: [
                                                            Text(
                                                                "Total money spent during",
                                                                style:
                                                                    semiBold18()),
                                                            SizedBox(
                                                              width:
                                                                  double.maxFinite,
                                                              child: Wrap(
                                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                    WrapCrossAlignment
                                                                        .center,
                                                                alignment:
                                                                    WrapAlignment
                                                                        .spaceBetween,
                                                                children: [
                                                                  DropdownButton(
                                                                      value: dropDownItems[
                                                                          dropDownMenuItemIndex],
                                                                      items: dropDownItems
                                                                          .map(
                                                                              (value) {
                                                                        return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                                          value:
                                                                              value,
                                                                          child: Text(
                                                                              value),
                                                                        );
                                                                      }).toList(),
                                                                      onChanged:
                                                                          (_) {
                                                                        setState(
                                                                            () {
                                                                          dropDownMenuItemIndex =
                                                                              dropDownItems
                                                                                  .indexOf(_!);
                                                                        });
                                                                      }),
                                                                  Row(
                                                                    mainAxisSize:
                                                                        MainAxisSize
                                                                            .min,
                                                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                        CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                            .center,
                                                                    children: [
                                                                      Text(NumberFormat(
                                                                              "#,###.##")
                                                                          .format(
                                                                              moneySpent)),
                                                                      IconButton(
                                                                          onPressed:(){...}
                                                                          icon: const Icon(
                                                                              Icons
                                                                                  .edit),
),
                                                                    ],
                                                                  ),
                                                                ],
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                          ],),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height:
                                                MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                    5 /
                                                    12,
                                            child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: [
                                                TabBar(
                                                  tabs: tabs,
                                                  isScrollable: true,
                                                  tabAlignment: TabAlignment.center,
                                                ),
                                                Expanded(
                                                  child: ConstrainedBox(
                                                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                                        minHeight:
                                                            MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                                    .size
                                                                    .height /
                                                                4),
                                                    child: TabBarView(
                                                      children: views,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(
                                            height: 20,
                                          ),)


Theres no difference bw my code and your code, you just removed the scrollbar and added a crossaxis alignment, and obvi it still doesnt work

Thanks to @Md. Yeasin Sheikh i removed height of the stats column and it is fixed.
return Scaffold(
body: DefaultTabController(
                          initialIndex: defaultGraphTabIndex,
                          length: views.length,
                          child: SafeArea(
                            child: Scrollbar(
                              controller: _scrollController,
                              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                controller: _scrollController,
                                child: Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 18, left: 18, right: 18),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      // Stats Column:
                                      Column(
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(
                                            // height: (MediaQuery.of(context)
                                            //             .size
                                            //             .height >=
                                            //         MediaQuery.of(context)
                                            //             .size
                                            //             .width)
                                            //     ? MediaQuery.of(context)
                                            //             .size
                                            //             .height *
                                            //         1 /
                                            //         6
                                            //     : MediaQuery.of(context)
                                            //             .size
                                            //             .width *
                                            //         1 /
                                            //         6,
                                            child: Wrap(
                                              spacing: 16,
                                              children: [
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: double.maxFinite,
                                                  child: Wrap(
                                                      spacing: 8,
                                                      alignment: WrapAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Text(
                                                            "Total money spent during",
                                                            style:
                                                                semiBold18()),
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          width:
                                                              double.maxFinite,
                                                          child: Wrap(
                                                            crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                WrapCrossAlignment
                                                                    .center,
                                                            alignment:
                                                                WrapAlignment
                                                                    .spaceBetween,
                                                            children: [
                                                              DropdownButton(
                                                                  value: dropDownItems[
                                                                      dropDownMenuItemIndex],
                                                                  items: dropDownItems
                                                                      .map(
                                                                          (value) {
                                                                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                                      value:
                                                                          value,
                                                                      child: Text(
                                                                          value),
                                                                    );
                                                                  }).toList(),
                                                                  onChanged:
                                                                      (_) {
                                                                    setState(
                                                                        () {
                                                                      dropDownMenuItemIndex =
                                                                          dropDownItems
                                                                              .indexOf(_!);
                                                                    });
                                                                  }),
                                                              Row(
                                                                mainAxisSize:
                                                                    MainAxisSize
                                                                        .min,
                                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                                    CrossAxisAlignment
                                                                        .center,
                                                                children: [
                                                                  Text(NumberFormat(
                                                                          "#,###.##")
                                                                      .format(
                                                                          moneySpent)),
                                                                  IconButton(
                                                                      onPressed:(){...}
                                                                      icon: const Icon(
                                                                          Icons
                                                                              .edit))
                                                                ],
                                                              )
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ]),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                                5 /
                                                12,
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: [
                                            TabBar(
                                              tabs: tabs,
                                              isScrollable: true,
                                              tabAlignment: TabAlignment.center,
                                            ),
                                            Expanded(
                                              child: ConstrainedBox(
                                                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                                    minHeight:
                                                        MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                                .size
                                                                .height /
                                                            4),
                                                child: TabBarView(
                                                  children: views,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        height: 20,
                                      ),)

